# The collective noun for cultures from different sites (blood, urine etc.)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, collective-nouns

What is the collective noun for microbiological cultures from different sites (blood, urine, feces etc.)? 
For example:

> "Data on ___________ [*cultures from different sites (blood, urine etc.)*] were collected from the department of clinical
>   microbiology."

Comment: An unpalatability of cultures?

Comment: Your example sentence is wrong, unless you mean that the *data* were collected from the department.  Further, no quotes around "cultures".

Comment: This is going to be difficult, as the word "culture" itself is a collective noun describing what's usually a large group of whatever it is you're going to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely talking of ***specimens***.

> "Data on ***specimens*** was collected from the department of clinical microbiology."

M-W:

> **[specimen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specimens)**
>   *noun*
>   **1 b** :  a portion or quantity of material for use in testing, examination, or study : *a urine specimen*

ODO:

> **[specimen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/specimen)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1.2** A sample for medical testing, especially of urine.
>
> ‘Specimens of blood or urine are the alternatives…’

Comment: This is great. Other than specimen, I can only think of "test samples" but that is a less precise term.

Comment: Good word, but it's not a collective noun.  (Tho' the OP probably doesn't care)

Answer (score 0):

‘Panel’ is the collective noun that physicians themselves often use. (You seem to be asking for the term of venery rather than a generic collective noun.) A panel of specimens from a single patient, might include different fluids and tissue types.